# How to filter .exe files from text file

Tags: bash, grep

This is an example line from the file:

> O4 - HKLM..\Run: [TkBellExe] C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Real\Update_OB\realsched.exe (RealNetworks, Inc.)

I just need **realsched.exe**

```
egrep '^O4' file.txt | egrep '[[:alnum:]]{0,99}\.exe'
```

Vague, but the closest thing that works. (Ignore the first grep, using that to find 4 lines)
But when the exe file has characters such as `_` then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ LINE='O4 - HKLM..\Run: [TkBellExe] C:\Program Files\Common Files\Real\Update_OB\realsched.exe (RealNetworks, Inc.)'
$ echo "$LINE" | egrep -o '[^\\]+\.exe'
realsched.exe
```

Comment: Perfect! Will vote in 8 mins. Can you explain the syntax, I'm new to this.

Comment: @kedar It matches any amount of characters that isn't a slash followed by '.exe', since it can't match slashes the whole path is left behind. The `-o` parameter of egrep makes it only output what it matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add underscore to your character set. For example, '[[:alnum:]_]{0,99}.exe'. You need to include all characters that are acceptable as a file name (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).

Comment: That works too. But the list would be long(of valid characters).
Will this work ok in avoiding those?

egrep -o '[^\\\?\|\:\*\%\/\>\<]*\.exe' file.txt

Also how do I avoid outputs such as '.exe' with nothing before the dot.

Comment: @kedar In my example, you can use the `+` operator instead of `*` to avoid matching a '.exe' string. And trying to match the valid filename characters would be overkill, but it's the best way to do it.

Comment: @KurzedMetal That seems to work. But instead I get *.exe in the output. But the file is at fault as it contains *.exe. To avoid both I tried "egrep -o '[^\\\*]+\.exe' file.txt" 

Works fine.